# Permitir somente números em um input

Tags: javascript

Tenho dois campos de input, latitude e longitude. Nele só devo permitir a entrada de números, sinal - e . como posso fazer uma função para isso?

Comment: Link da resposta-> [Vai ter que usar mascara de entrada no input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516374/jquery-decimal-mask-for-latitude)

Comment: Um `<input type='number'>` não serve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando essa função abaixo você limita as teclas que o usuário pode digitar, no seu caso: números, sinal (`-`) e ponto ( `.` )

```js
var filtroTeclas = function(event) {
  return ((event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode == 45 || event.charCode == 46))
}
```

```css
label {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="latitude">Latitude:</label>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="latitude" onkeypress='return filtroTeclas(event)' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="latitude">Longitude:</label>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="latitude" onkeypress='return filtroTeclas(event)' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```